# Unit Testing and system robustness estimation

Tags: unit-testing, testing

When I watch a rocket launch in TV, I heard the reporter says "...the overall reliability of the rocket is 95.6%...". A rocket is made of many small parts, just like a big piece of software is made of many classes (units).

I think the overall reliability of a rocket is based upon the individual reliability of each part and some mathematics calculation. **So if we can use Unit Testing to verify that a software unit does work. Can we achieve a similar estimation for the overall reliability of the whole software?** I think this estimation should be useful.

Comment: I don't know how they come to that figure, but I'm quite sure its not much more than gut feeling. (Btw.: What does "...the overall reliability of the rocket is 95.6%..." mean anyway??) A system cannot be assessed only by its individual parts. Equally important is how they are put together.

Comment: I agree. Due to the similarity, I think there should be some way to quantify the reliability of the software system.